# Does RollingFileAppender create log file on disk?

Tags: logging, logback, spring-logback

I have written following appender to logback-spring.xml. I would like to know if log/service.log
is created on disk or memory

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>log/service.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>log/service-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>    
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>100GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```